# How to fetch data from different origin CORS?

Tags: javascript, cors, http-headers, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch data from a different origin to another server using `Fetch API` and I precise is from `http` to `https`

I can read the data from my browser but I don't know how to fetch them.

I already tried to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to  `*` but I still get this message :

[image: console]

I'm a little bit lost right know, Thank you for your support.

```
const myHeaders = new Headers({
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
});

const fetchConfig = {
  method: "GET",
  headers: myHeaders,
  mode: "cors",
  cache: "no-cache"
};

function fetchData(url) {

  fetch(url, fetchConfig)
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));

}

fetchData("https://api.example.com/");
```

Comment: I don't know if it's a problem of my browser, but I can't see the error image you posted. Can you paste the text please?

Comment: did you try  `console.log(response)` after `than` , what is the response you are getting ??

Comment: Easy topic to research. Always try searching before asking. That error term alone will bring up many many results

Answer (score 3):

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header needs to be set by the server you are retrieving the data from, in response to your request.

Answer (score 1):

`CORS Anywhere` is a NodeJS proxy which adds CORS headers to the proxied request.

The URL to the proxy is literally taken from the path, validated and proxied. The protocol part of the proxied URI is optional, and defaults to "http". If port 443 is specified, the protocol defaults to "https".

This package does not put any restrictions on the http methods or headers, except for cookies. Requesting user credentials is disallowed. The app can be configured to require a header for proxying a request, for example, to avoid a direct visit from the browser.

You can simply add https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ at the beginning of your url.
Like this `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://example.com/api/...`.

Check this link for more details: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere